# How to get jsonpathquery or Xpathquery for columns in talend?

Tags: talend

```
tFileInputJson--> component --> Basic settings--> Mapping
```

How can we get  jsonpathquery or Xpathquery for columns in talend:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to declare a JSON metadata for input file (Repository>Metadata>Json File). There, based on an existing jsonfile, you'll be able to get json query for all the fields.

See talend help : https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforDataIntegrationUserGuide62EN/7.11.1+Setting+up+JSON+metadata+for+an+input+file